# How can I modify vertices, edges and faces in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

This ultimate newbie question has come from trying to imitate the simple playing around with the Object that the instructor does after 1:58 in this video:

https://youtu.be/v8XSQhRcpfM?t=118

I am in edit mode and can click on vertices, edges, and faces, but can't drag them around the way he does. Also, if I am not wrong about this the Transforms don't seem to be locked.
[image: With Transforms locked/unlocked status (I think?)]

Pressing "O" doesn't seem to make a difference either, and I have approached the tip of pressing the period key and unticking Only Locations but when I press the period key I don't see that.
[image: After pressing the period key]

All help and thoughts put into this are appreciated

Comment: Have you pressed G to move the vertex?

Comment: If you're using the tools in the toolbar on the left, try hitting 'W' until you cycle to the 'Tweak' tool. Then you'll be able to left-click-and-drag selections.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) I hadn't been pressing G